# Class 'Product' should have [public, protected] no-arg constructor

Tags: java, spring, lombok

Нужна ваша помощь. У меня есть класс `Product`. К нему есть привязана аннотация `@AllArgsConstrucrot`. У меня есть показывается ошибка: `Class 'Product' should have [public, protected] no-arg constructor`.Данная аннотация не имеет решать эту проблему, или я ошибаюсь? В чем ошибка? Спасибо

```
package com.example_dmytrii_cherniak.java_application.entity;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;

@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity

public class Product {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;
@Column(nullable = false, length = 99)
private String title;
private int price;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@AllArgsConstructor - генерирует конструктор со всеми возможными аргументами
@NoArgsConstructor - генерирует конструктор без аргументов

Добавь @NoArgsConstructor

Советую почитать документацию к ломбоку: https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor

Answer (score 0):

В спецификации JPA п. 37.1.1 (https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-intro001.htm#BNBQA) среди прочего указано

> The class must have a public or protected, no-argument constructor. The class may have other constructors.

Т. е. сущность ОБЯЗАНА иметь конструктор без аргументов. Указывая `@AllArgsConstructor`, Вы оставляете единственный конструктор со всеми аргументами, т.е. в Вашем случае

```
public Product(int id, String title, int price) {
this.id = id;
this.title = title;
this.price = price;
}
```

Как указал [Gleb Kuznetsov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/11291/gleb-kuznetsov) - выходом станет добавление классу аннотации `@NoArgsConstructor`